# Check if time is in between two times

Tags: php, time

I have a deal which is available on every Friday from 22:00 to 4:00. But the problem is that after 00:00 it will turn to Saturday and my code will no longer find the deal.

Here is how I save the deals:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [offerAvailableOn] => 5
            [open] => 22:00 
            [close] =>  04:00
        )
}
```

And this is my code to query for it:

```
$today = date('N');
$timeNow = date('H:i');
```

But when $today is Saturday, it won't find my offer.

Comment: This is a case where it is needed to include the day of the week in the `open` and `close` variables. Don't use a single `offerAvailableOn` variable to indicate the day of the week.

Comment: @jenifer you got some advance with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `open` and `close` variables to include the day of the week. Have a look at this page of the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

So `open` could be `'Friday 22:00'` en `close` could be `'Saturday 04:00'`. In PHP that would look like this:

```
$deal = array('open'  => 'Friday 22:00',
              'close' => 'Saturday 04:00');

echo 'deal open: '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($deal['open'])).'<br>';
echo 'deal close: '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($deal['close']));
```

For me this gives now:

```
deal open: 2014-10-24 22:00:00
deal close: 2014-10-18 04:00:00
```

Notice that the deal `open` time is bigger that the current time. So you have to think about your `if` conditions:

```
$open  = strtotime($deal['open']);
$close = strtotime($deal['close']);
$now   = time();

$dealIsOn = (($open > $now) && ($close < $now));
```

Which might seem counter-intuitive at first, but is correct.

Also notice that this system is quite flexible. With the same code you can select a day of the month. However, for a absolute dates you have to do another check:

```
$open  = strtotime('2014-10-25 22:00:00');
$close = strtotime('2014-10-26 22:00:00');
$now   = time();

$dealIsOn = (($open < $now) && ($close > $now));
```

So I would introduce a flag in the array indicating whether or not the `open` and `close` variables are absolute or relative.

Comment: Nice. And much less complexity than using absolute dates or some recurring pattern solution.

Comment: thank you for giving your precious time,I have managed my array like-Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 5
            [open] => 22:00 
            [close] =>  04:00
            [timenow] => 01:27
            [today] => 6
        ) can you please help me with this data,according to the above data even though today is '6' i.e. Saturday but the offer should be available.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Also, please do not use comments to ask new questions. Create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to two tests. The offer is available Friday at 22:00 or later and Saturday at 4:00 or earlier.